# Duration. Floating rate note

Tags: interest-rates, bond, duration

I don't understand why the duration of a floating rate note equal to the time to the next coupon payment?
Please, look at my calculations.

Here: P - is price at moment 0.

[image]

Comment: The definition of duration for these purposes is the Price sensitivity to a bump in interest rates.  Try to calculate that , assuming that the first coupon has been fixed.

Comment: In my calculations first coupon is fixed and equals L_0,6. Where L_0,6 is half-year LIBOR rate, which is fixed in the moment 0.

Comment: So, in my calculations the duration equals 1 (not 1/2 - time to the fitst coupon payment).. Why is so?

Comment: Shouldn’t be.  Let the first coupon be c, and let all other rates move, including L(0,6)

Comment: Ok. What wrong in the formula? I used the simple definition of a duration, which you can find in Wikipedia..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the first coupon be fixed at c, and consider the duration of the bond immediately thereafter.  At this point $L_(0,6)$ can move.  Now in your notation you should find that $$P=N(1+c/2)/(1+L_(0,6)/2)$$.   Now if you calculate $(1/P)dP/dL$ you get $1/2* (1/(1+L/2))$ which is 1/2, discounted for 6 months, where $L=L_(0,6)$.